# How can i use the closed power outlets

Tags: electrical

*I am Greek so my English wont be perfect, forgive me.*

I have this power strip with 3 "spots" for a year now.

I plugged in something today in one spot, then unplugged. Everything as usual. Ever since, I cant plug in anything else. I apply force, i wiggle, i followed other advice i found online, nothing!

What happened all of a sudden?

[image]

Comment: Why are you showing a close-up pic of the left spot when it is the middle spot that no longer works?

Comment: The middle spot works just fine. This one doesnt.

Comment: A retaining spring in the middle spot appears to be bent out of place and quite crushed. Is it just an effect of the photo? - The reason I'm looking at the middle spot instead of at the problem you asked about is, if the entire power strip is battered then it should be no surprise that it has failed somewhere.

Comment: Is it expensive to replace? I have repaired power strips and similar devices but the result is *always* more dangerous to use than when it was new.

Comment: The middle spot is fine, i dont know why it looks like that in the photo. It is not very expensive but we re on lockdown in greece, all stores are closed and online delivery requires weeks. There is no way to fix it at least temporarily? I mean, it doesnt make sense to me that i cant plug in anything. Why is there such a ressistance even though o apply force and wiggle? It has never happened to me before

Comment: Adding a clear photo of the middle or right outlets may help us play spot the difference to see if we can see anything different.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. I thought you plugged it in and it didn't work. - If you can't push the plug into the spot then that's different.

Answer (score 1):

What probably has happened is that one of the retaining clips has become bent too far toward the center and is blocking the plug. Press the clips outward as far as you can, and make sure the plug can push them both into their slots.

You shouldn't remove the clips as they probably also supply safety fault grounding.